# Erro ao dar refresh no report viewer C#

Tags: c#, winforms, relatório, reportviewer

Estou com um problema ao executar um relatório em report viewer no c#.

O problema é o seguinte eu tenho que adicionar uma lista no data source, 
porém ele adiciona a primeira lista, depois não atualiza mais.

O Que pode ser ?

Exemplo do código.

```
            List<auxFertilizanteRel> lstFert = new List<auxFertilizanteRel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ccbOpcaoFertilizante.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ccbOpcaoFertilizante.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                var listFertilizante = pFertilizante.ReturnAllByCiclo(ObjCiclo.objID, int.Parse(ccbOpcaoFertilizante.Items[i].ToString()), true);
                var vMediaFertilizantes = cFertilizante.ReturnMedia(ObjCiclo, int.Parse(ccbOpcaoFertilizante.Items[i].ToString()));
                foreach (var item in listFertilizante)
                {
                    auxFertilizanteRel list = new auxFertilizanteRel();
                    list.cabecalho = ccbOpcaoFertilizante.Items[i].ToString();
                    list.codigoEstagio = item.codigoEstagio;
                    list.objID = item.objID;
                    list.descricao = item.descricao;
                    list.kgha = item.kgha;
                    list.daedap = item.daedap;
                    list.n = item.n;
                    list.p2o5 = item.p2o5;
                    list.k2o = item.k2o;
                    list.s = item.s;
                    list.ca = item.ca;
                    list.mg = item.mg;
                    list.b = item.b;
                    list.zn = item.zn;
                    list.cu = item.cu;
                    list.mn = item.mn;
                    list.co = item.co;
                    list.mo = item.mo;
                    list.marcado = item.marcado;
                    list.IDEstagioCultura = item.IDEstagioCultura;
                    list.IDCicloProducao = item.IDCicloProducao;
                    list.IDFornecedor = item.IDFornecedor;
                    list.opcao = item.opcao;
                    list.opcaoMarcada = item.opcaoMarcada;
                    list.eficiencia = item.eficiencia;
                    lstFert.Add(list);
                }
            }
        }
   reportAnalises.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ("dsFertilizante", lstFert))

        this.reportAnalises.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
        this.reportAnalises.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;
        this.reportAnalises.LocalReport.SetParameters(parametros);
        this.btnEnviarPdf.Enabled = true;

        this.reportAnalises.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Ja tentou limpar o reportAnalises.LocalReport.DataSources  antes de adicionar novamente?

Comment: Sim utilizei no início da estrutura

Comment: Utilizei esse código "this.reportAnalises.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();"

Só que quando eu pressiono o botão para gerar o relatório ele acusa, falando que não existe dados para dsFertilizante

Comment: Seu exemplo esta correto mesmo? No DataSources.Add, você realmente está adicionando uma tupla direto? Não deveria ser um ReportDataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione o DataSource da seguinte forma:

```
//limpa datasources
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

//carrega relatório
using (var st = typeof(DocumentRenderer).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("meu_relatorio.rdlc")) {
reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(st);
}

//seta datasource e faz refresh do relatório
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsFertilizante", myCtx.ReportDataTerm));

//atualiza o relatório
reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: @MichelOliveira bom dia, editei a resposta com a solução que utilizo aqui. Veja se dessa forma funciona.